# RabbitMQ / .NET integration - "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure", but the cert is valid

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ integration built in a .NET Standard library, which is being used by a few .NET Framework 4.7.2 apps. It's configured to connect to the RabbitMQ broker securely over port 5671 with a self-signed cert that has been installed in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities of my local machine and our app development/testing server.

Both the development server and the RabbitMQ broker are running on AWS EC2 instances within our "local" network.

When I run these apps in debug on my local machine (connected to the "local" network through a VPN), the secure connection to the RabbitMQ broker is initialized correctly, and everything works as expected.

When I try to run the apps on the development server, however, the connection fails with the following exception:

```
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +8343681
   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) +76
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +83
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts) +82
   RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options) +512
   RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout) +830
   RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint) +122
   RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne(IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector) +191
```

What's even more weird is that, when I navigate to the secure RabbitMQ Management UI (port 15671) through a browser on the development server, the browser correctly recognizes the certificate as valid.

Thinking this may be a firewall/port issue, I made sure that the development server firewall was set to allow outbound TCP traffic to port 5671, but this also hasn't fixed the issue.

What am I missing? Is there some extra IIS configuration needed for this that I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: Open csproj file with notepad and check if the SSSL/TLS option is using the default operating system or Net.  If Net change to to default (remove line in project file).  If using operating system than there is issues with operating system.  What version of Windows is being used?  If Core you may need to update kernel on machine.

Comment: OS is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. I don't see any option for default SSL/TLS in the .csproj - I'm assuming that means it's using the default operating system? What would the option look like?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#switchsystemnetdontenablesystemdefaulttlsversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be rather simple. I had mistakenly installed the cert in the development server's *admin user* Trusted Root Authorities, rather than the *machine's* Trusted Root Authorities. Since the application was set up to run with a different user, that user didn't have access to the installed cert. Once I had installed it in the machine's Trusted Root Authorities, the connection worked as expected.

Props to Luke Bakken from the RabbitMQ team for the answer: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/tJHnDEnCZxM

Comment: Thanks for following up here!